# Failing to connect to MSSQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I've installed [SQL Server 2012 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062). The problem is that I cannot connect to it through MSQL Server Management Studio.

When installing it, I've used `MSSQLSERVER` as an instance name. I have SQL 2017 running as `SQLEXPRESS`.

Checking at the services, I can see that it's running.

[image]

And here is the image of management studio.

[image]

You can see that I am connected to `\SQLEXPRESS` and for some reason it keeps failing to connect to `\MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: @DanGuzman That worked. I connected to `DINOD198\`. Thanks (feel free to post an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `MSSQLSERVER` is the default instance rather than the name of a named instance. Unlike a named instance (like the `SQLEXPRESS` instance), the instance name is not specified to connect to the default instance. One can connect to the default instance using the host name alone (assuming default 1433 port) or host name and port number. For a local connection, `.` or `localhost` can be specified.